# How to set UIImageView zoom animation when the photo being changed

Tags: ios, objective-c, animation, uiimageview, zooming

As title, I am beginner so i don't have idea to solve it.

In my code, it just have zoom animation when i turn on the emulator first time,

I want to have the zoom animation when each photo change,

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
     NSArray *animationImages = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:[UIImage imageNamed:@"1.jpg"],
                                [UIImage imageNamed:@"2.jpg"],
                                [UIImage imageNamed:@"3.jpg"],
                                [UIImage imageNamed:@"4.jpg"],nil];

    UIImageView *imageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(10,10,300,300)];
    imageView.animationImages = animationImages ;
    imageView.animationRepeatCount = 0;
    imageView.animationDuration= 12.0;
    [imageView startAnimating];
    [self.view addSubview:imageView];

    imageView.frame = CGRectMake(150, 150, 20, 20);
    CGPoint center = imageView.center;
    [UIView animateWithDuration: 1.0f animations:^{
        imageView.frame = CGRectMake(10, 10, 300, 300);
        imageView.center = center;
    }];
}
```

Thank you in advance for any assistance that can be provided here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not the cleanest code to use `animationImages` if you want a zoom animation on each image transition. I would create my own custom `UIView` class to handle the transitions myself so the animations can be tightly synchronized with each transition. But, for the sake of answering your question with a quick unreliable hack, I will use a timer to run an animation at approximately the same frequency as the image transitions. Timers become less accurate over time due, so eventually the zoom effect no longer lines up with the image transitions.

```
@interface NameOfYourViewController ()

@property(nonatomic, strong) UIImageView* imageView;
@property(nonatomic, strong) NSTimer* imageTransitionTimer;
@property(nonatomic, assign) CGFloat imageScale;
- (void)animateImage;

@end

@implementation NameOfYourViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
     NSArray *animationImages = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:[UIImage imageNamed:@"1.jpg"],
                                [UIImage imageNamed:@"2.jpg"],
                                [UIImage imageNamed:@"3.jpg"],
                                [UIImage imageNamed:@"4.jpg"],nil];

    self.imageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(10,10,300,300)];
    selfimageView.animationImages = animationImages ;
    self.imageView.animationRepeatCount = 0;
    self.imageView.animationDuration= 12.0;
    [self.imageView startAnimating];
    [self.view addSubview:self.imageView];

    self.imageScale = 1.0f;
    self.imageTransitionTimer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:imageView.animationDuration target:self selector:@selector(animateImage) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];
    [self.imageTransitionTimer fire];
}

- (void)animateImage
{
   [UIView 
     animateWithDuration:1.0 
     delay:0.0
     options:0
     animations:^void () {
       self.imageView.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeScale(
         self.imageScale,
         self.imageScale 
       );
     }
     completion:^void(BOOL finished) {
       self.imageScale += 0.3f;
     }
   }]; 
}

@end
```

Comment: thanks for your comment, but the function of animateImage it can't pass compiler, i m wondering how to solve it

Comment: @hungwei0331 I never tested my code in Xcode. I just typed it all on StackOverflow. I have done all the hard work for you. You just need to do the easy work of compiling it. It's probably a spelling error or unmatched ) ] }.